# Terminology: Probability "with respect to a measure"

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, bayesian

The following excerpt is taken from [Shen and Wasserman (2001)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1009210686).

> [image]

I have difficulty understanding some terminologies. 
On line 4,

> [...] each $P_\eta$ is a probability on $(\mathscr Y,\mathscr B)$ with density $p(y\mid\eta)$ with respect to a common, dominating, $\sigma$-finite measure $\lambda$.

In particular, what do the authors mean by saying a probability (distribution) is **with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure**?

Comment: It is only _density_, not a distribution, that is with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: What does a probability density with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure mean then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on a $\sigma$-field, and $f$ is a $\mu$-measurable function, and $f\ge 0$ everywhere (or *almost* everywhere, if you like).  For every $\mu$-measurable set $A$, let
$$
\nu(A) = \int_A f\,d\mu.
$$
Then $f$ is the *density* of the measure $\nu$ with respect to the measure $\mu$.  It's also called the Radon–Nikodym derivative, and one writes $f=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}$.

For example, if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on the line $\mathbb R$, then the measure that $\mu$ assigns to every interval is its length.  If $\nu$ is the standard normal distribution on the line, then density of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ is
$$
\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}. 
$$

As another example, suppose $\mu$ is "counting measure" on the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, so that, for example, $\mu(\{1,2,4,6\})=4$.  Then the density with respect to $\mu$ of the binomial distribution with parameters $4$ and $1/2$ is $f(x) = \dbinom 4 x (1/2)^4$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Perhaps you may help me with my other, yet unanswered, question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140024/70119) as well?